# AC coupling of a transistor

Tags: transistors, coupling, biasing

[image: proper bias assumed.]

So we assume to have proper bias currents flowing in both of the two transistors. What is claimed by books is that a capacitive coupling will not change the bias parameters.
But, we know that a capacitor will charge and hence gain voltage across it. Now this capacitor voltage is applied back to the transistor, in our case the voltage will be applied to the collector of the first and the base of the second transistor and hence will change the bias parameters!

What is wrong in my reasoning?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Neither of your transistors is biassed in the diagram. It would help you reason about the coupling capacitor if you made the biassing explicit.

Comment: I thought it was obvious but yes that would help. Thank you Dear Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find an answer to your question, you should draw the bias circuits. Then you will see that, after the power is turned on, the capacitor will begin charging and really, until it is fully charged, it will affect the output voltage Vc1 of the first stage (Q1) and the input voltage Vb2 of the second stage (Q2). It is preferable the input voltage to be zero until this initial process finishes. Also, it would be very useful to draw the path where the current flows.

After the capacitor is charged, the current through it becomes zero and the capacitor stop affecting the voltages. Figuratively speaking, it has copied the difference Vc1 - Vb2 = VC across itself so you can think of it as of a charged "rechargeable battery". You probably understand why the capacitor cannot be with too high capacity - since during this initial transition process, the amplifier does not work correctly.

Now increase the input voltage and you will see how the capacitor conveys Q1 collector voltage variations to Q2 base since the voltage across the capacitor cannot change significantly. Again you can use a metaphor to imagine visually this "AC voltage shifting" technique. Think of the capacitor as of a stiff bar firmly joining Q1 collector and Q2 base. When Q1 collector "moves",  it "pulls" up and down Q2 base... so it follows Q1 collector "movement".

Comment: Thank you . I agree that no current flows via cap however there is a voltage across it, which is applied back to the transistor,and since transistor is voltage dependant it will then change its bias values.

Comment: @YasirSadiq, that voltage across the cap is just the same as the difference between what the voltage at the two connection points would have been if the cap wasn't there. The presence of the cap doesn't change the bias point for either of the transistors.

Comment: @The photon Thank you, what's your proof for that.

Comment: @Yasir go solve the problem both ways and see if you get different answers.

Comment: Thank you I understood it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you said 'biased at', that is the DC operating point. By analyzing the DC voltages with no input, several key parameters are measured/calculated. Some of these are transconductance, gain, I_C, and input/output impedance.

Adding a cap to a DC-biased circuit will not affect the operating point once it charges to the node voltages. There is no DC current through the cap, so at DC the cap is perceived as an open.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I agree that no current flows via cap however there is a voltage across it, which is applied back to the transistor.